# Change which linux install "controls" grub

Tags: grub2

I was having some issues I was trying to narrow down so I made a small partition and threw Fedora on it. Well, I wasn't paying attention and Fedora's grub is now "in control" so to speak. If I want to edit grub's menu, I have to do it in Fedora (any changes made in Ubuntu won't register)

Basically, today, I wiped my ubuntu partition, formatted it, split off 15gb, reinstalled xubuntu from the live CD, then installed Fedora immediately after on the 15gb partition, which overwrote Xubunutu's grub.

How can I flip it back so Ubuntu is in control of grub, rather than Fedora, preferably without reformatting and reinstalling again (I just finally got everything set back up)

Or do they both control it and I just missed something? I changed the boot order in Ubuntu (along with which was the default) but it didn't take, using Grub Customizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to reinstall the xubuntu-grub on the Master Boot Record of your hard drive. Just type `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` from ubuntu and ubuntu will be back in control.

Comment: That worked, more or less. The problem was redoing the grub menu to reflect Fedora, and I couldn't mount the Fedora partition in Ubuntu without some googling. Essentially:
`sudo apt-get install lvm2`
`sudo modprobe dm-mod`
`sudo vgchange -a y`
Which then mounted the Fedora partition, followed with
`sudo grub-install /dev/sda`
`sudo update-grub`
Rebooted and all is fine. Problem was finding a starting point, didn't know about `grub-install /dev/sda` so thanks!